# Most efficient way to delete duplicate entries from MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mariadb, sql-delete

We have a table (let us call it `originalTbl`) that has duplicate entries that we want to delete.  By duplicate I mean all values other than an **AUTO INCREMENT** index field are the same.  One way to do this is to create a new table, like the existing table (let us call it `uniqueTbl`), and then have a query like:

```
INSERT INTO uniqueTbl (non-Index-field_1, non-Index-field_2, …, non-Index-field_n)
SELECT DISTINCT non-Index-field_1, non-Index-field_2, …, non-Index-field_n FROM originalTbl;
```

Later on we will drop `originalTbl` and rename `uniqueTbl` to `originalTbl`.

---

However, I am looking for an alternate approach, that will delete the duplicate entries from `originalTbl` directly, without the overhead of first creating the `uniqueTbl` and then renaming it to `originalTbl`.

Comment: Your method is going to be much, much faster than deleting entries in the original table -- unless you have very few duplciates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very few duplicates, your method will be much, much faster.  If you only have a few (say less than 1%), then you can try:

```
delete o
    from originalTbl o left join
         (select col1, col2, . . ., min(id) as min_id
          from originalTbl o
          group by col1, col2, . . .
         ) oo
         on oo.min_id = o.id
    where oo.min_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a self-join. Assuming that you have three columns other than `id`, that would look like:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join (
    select col1, col2, col3, min(id) minid 
    from mytable
    group by col1, col2, col3
) t1
    on  t.col1 = t1.col1
    and t.col2 = t1.col2
    and t.col3 = t1.col3
    and t.id > t.minid
```

This deletes the duplicates will retaining the row that has the smallest `id`.

That said, the method you originally showed is very likely to be much faster than this. The overhead you get by renaming the table is quite small.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion.  It will attempt to delete the same row multiple times.

Comment: . . I should be more precise.  Your original version is fine if there are like 10 duplicates in a million records and a single group is only duplicated once.  As a *general* solution, it is a bad suggestion.  Good morning (it is morning where I am).

Comment: Good morning @GordonLinoff! Yes I understood your point, no issue. I changed the query to aggregate before joining, so if there multiple duplicates each is only selected/deleted once. Cheers.